# How can I store collection of objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
# data = {blah blah};

for object in my_queryset():
    object.data = data
```

But I want to return the original query set with new data. how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn it into a list so it's stored in memory and not just an iterable.

```
data = {blah blah}
objects = list(my_queryset())
for object in objects:
    object.data = data
return objects
```

Comment: what is the diff if we don't convert to list

Comment: you can only iterate over it once

Comment: ok thanks , so u mean if we didn't convert to list then after making chnages to object we will not see those chnages in list or it wont exist after first call